How can I loosen a frost hydrant collar nut frozen due to corrosion?
My frost hydrant was stuck shut so I took out the assembly to diagnose. It was easy to see that the lever assembly lost grip on the rod it reciprocates because the rod got caked to the collar nut that it should be sliding in while the nut remains static. I have been unable to remove the nut even with wrenches, it is stuck pretty good.


Do I keep trying to unstuck the nut by force? If I do get it off, do I need to replace it or can I just reinstall it? Last but not least, I recently (6 months ago?) replaced most of the head assembly with a repair kit. Could it be that I misplaced an O ring that caused corrosion and sticking? Or could it be that keeping the hydrant in the on position (for a garden hose) could have caused it?

Are you aware that you can focus your phone by touching the screen?

You don't mention penetrating oil or similar. That's usually step 2 in cases like this. Step 3 is heat (short of damaging soft seals).

Usually if wrenches do not loosen it, you try bigger wrenches/cheat bars(pipes).  But soaking in penetrating oil and giving it a few taps(for vibration) should usually work.  The oil might take some time(day/s) to soak in.

This question is similar to: How to loosen a rusted nut/screw. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also How to move nut that is corroded onto tap?

@isherwood -- that is not as specific as my question because in my case, the context is important, like the constant water exposure, pressure etc, because it is a frost hydrant. so no, i don't think it's a duplicate exactly

Breaking a rusted nut free is one thing. Keeping it free with grease or whatever is another. The root cause is another. Your questions meander a bit, though, so it's hard to pin down the primary one. It's borderline off topic.
